# Submit empty string via POST wfs in GeoExt.form.FormPanel

Tags: wfs, geoext

I have a two textfields in FormPanel. When one of them is empty, after pressing the search button the form sends the empty string in WFS query. How can I disable the empty field which sends the WFS request after I pressed the search button?

```js
    formPanel = new GeoExt.form.FormPanel({
    ref: "formPanel",
    width: 300,
    height: 200,
    region: "west",
    protocol: protocol,
    buttons:[{
     text: "search",
     handler: function() {
         formPanel.getForm().search();
     },
     //scope: formPanel
 }],
    items: [{
        xtype: "textfield",
        name: "trans_id__eq",
        value: "",
        fieldLabel: "ID",
        disabled: true,
        ref: 'myTextField'
    },

    {
        xtype: "textfield",
        name: "nabywca__eq",
        value: "",
        fieldLabel: "nabywca",
        submitEmptyText: false 
    },
    ],
    listeners: {
        actioncomplete: function(form, action) {
        // this listener triggers when the search request
        // is complete, the OpenLayers.Protocol.Response
        // resulting from the request is available
        // through "action.response"
            features = action.response.features;
            app.featureGrid.store.loadData(features);   //załadowanie zwróconego wyniku wyszukiwania do "app.featureGrid.store"
            vm=app.mapPanel.map.getLayersByName("Results");
            if(vm.length==0){
                vecLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Results");
               app.mapPanel.map.addLayer(vecLayer);
                app.featureGrid.store.bind(vecLayer);
                app.featureGrid.getSelectionModel().bind(vecLayer);
            //app.featureGrid.getSelectionModel().bind(vectorLayer);
        }
    }
    }




})


    );
```

When I leave blank first textfield and put the value to the second my wfs request send empty string and I get the error.

My protocol:

```js
var protocol= OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({

            version: "1.1.0",
            url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs",
            featureType: "transakcje_punkty",
            featureNS: "http://geoserver.org/transakcje",
             srsName: "EPSG:900913"


        });
```

Wfs is working properly when I have one field, but I would like to add 7 "textfields".

The user fills the fields with the attributes he want to find and  rest leaves empty.

But empty field send some empty value to WFS and I get an error... instead results.

Comment: add some code to your question, so people can help you to solve your problem.

Comment: and where is your protocol?

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing

```
name: "trans_id__eq",
```

by

```
name: "transid__eq",
```

post also your protocol as part of your code, probably there is something wrong there.